# SQLAlchemy, scoped_session - raw SQL INSERT doesn't write to DB

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have a Pyramid / SQLAlchemy, MySQL python app. 
When I execute a raw SQL INSERT query, nothing gets written to the DB. 
When using ORM, however, I can write to the DB. I read the docs, I read up about the ZopeTransactionExtension, read a good deal of SO questions, all to no avail. 
What hasn't worked so far:

- `transaction.commit()` - nothing is written to the DB. I do realize this statement is necessary with ZopeTransactionExtension but it just doesn't do the magic here.
- `dbsession().commit` - doesn't work since I'm using ZopeTransactionExtension
- `dbsession().close()` - nothing written
- `dbsession().flush()` - nothing written
- `mark_changed(session)` -

> File "/home/dev/.virtualenvs/sc/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope/sqlalchemy/datamanager.py", line 198, in join_transaction
>   if session.twophase:
>   AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'twophase'"
>   
>   What has worked but is not acceptable because it doesn't use scoped_session:

- `engine.execute(...)`

I'm looking for how to execute raw SQL with a `scoped_session` (`dbsession()` in my code)

Here is my SQLAlchemy setup (`models/__init__.py`)

```
def dbsession():
    assert (_dbsession is not None)
    return _dbsession

def init_engines(settings, _testing_workarounds=False):
    import zope.sqlalchemy
    extension = zope.sqlalchemy.ZopeTransactionExtension()
    global _dbsession

    _dbsession = scoped_session(
        sessionmaker(
            autoflush=True,
            expire_on_commit=False,
            extension=extension,
        )
    )

    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    _dbsession.configure(bind=engine)
```

Here is a python script I wrote to isolate the problem. It resembles the real-world environment of where the problem occurs. All I want is to make the below script insert the data into the DB:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import transaction

from pyramid.paster import setup_logging, get_appsettings
from sc.models import init_engines, dbsession
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text


def __main__():

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    raise RuntimeError()
config_uri = sys.argv[1]
setup_logging(config_uri)
aa = init_engines(get_appsettings(config_uri))

session = dbsession()
session.execute(text("""INSERT INTO
         operations (description, generated_description)
         VALUES ('hello2', 'world');"""))

print list(session.execute("""SELECT * from operations""").fetchall()) # prints inserted data
transaction.commit()

print list(session.execute("""SELECT * from operations""").fetchall()) # doesn't print inserted data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    __main__()
```

What is interesting, if I do:

```
session = dbsession()
session.execute(text("""INSERT INTO
         operations (description, generated_description)
         VALUES ('hello2', 'world');"""))
op = Operation(generated_description='aa', description='oo')
session.add(op)
```

then the first print outputs the raw SQL inserted row ('hello2' 'world'), and the second print prints **both** rows, and in fact **both rows are inserted into the DB**.

I cannot comprehend why using an ORM insert alongside raw SQL "fixes" it.

I really need to be able to call execute() on a scoped_session to insert data into the DB using raw SQL. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been a while since I mixed raw sql with sqlalchemy, but whenever you mix them, you need to be aware of what happens behind the scenes with the ORM. First, check the [autocommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit) flag. If the zope transaction is not configured correctly, the ORM insert might be triggering a commit.

Actually, after looking at the zope docs, it seems manual execute statements need an extra step. From their [readme](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.sqlalchemy/tree/master/src/zope/sqlalchemy):

> By default, zope.sqlalchemy puts sessions in an 'active' state when they are
>   first used. ORM write operations automatically move the session into a
>   'changed' state. This avoids unnecessary database commits. Sometimes it
>   is necessary to interact with the database directly through SQL. It is not
>   possible to guess whether such an operation is a read or a write. Therefore we
>   must manually mark the session as changed when manual SQL statements write
>   to the DB.

```
>>> session = Session()
>>> conn = session.connection()
>>> users = Base.metadata.tables['test_users']
>>> conn.execute(users.update(users.c.name=='bob'), name='ben')
<sqlalchemy.engine...ResultProxy object at ...>
>>> from zope.sqlalchemy import mark_changed
>>> mark_changed(session)
>>> transaction.commit()
>>> session = Session()
>>> str(session.query(User).all()[0].name)
'ben'
>>> transaction.abort()
```

It seems you aren't doing that, and so the transaction.commit does nothing.

Comment: I tried what you advised, except in the conn.execute() I passed raw sql.

Comment: there are two differences between your code and my requirements:
1. I'm using scoped_session
2. I'm passing a raw SQL query

The problem is, mark_changed(session) throws an exception "AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'twophase'".

In the end, I refactored the problematic code to use ORM, and where I need to execute raw SQL, I use engine.execute().
I cannot see a way to commit raw SQL from a scoped_session with ZopeTransactionExtension (unless I use autocommit=True).

Comment: @PawelP In the zope docs, one of the options they pass to scope_session is `twophase=TEST_TWOPHASE`. Perhaps that would fix it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'd help. I can't test it right now but I guess you gave all the relevant info that could be given, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @PawelP You received that AttributeError because `mark_changed` expects the actual session object, not the scoped session (which normally proxies to the session). Passing a `twophase`option won't fix that, but getting the session object and using it instead of the scoped session will. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21162302/3123187 for how you'd do that.